# Database Size Support on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit) x64

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anybody please suggest how much size of database is supported in this edition on Sql Server "SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit) x64  Edition". I have Windows 7 on my machine and want to install this version. The database I am having to restore is of size 40 Gb. Does this edition supports this much size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'll just about cope given that the max size is 524,272 terabytes...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Go through this link which will tell you that it supports

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/24/60267.aspx